# sigsegv caused by AudioRecord?

Tags: android, segmentation-fault, android-mediaplayer, audio-recording, audiorecord

I am using AudioRecord and mediaplayer to record and play the audio.
what the app(Android app) does is automatically record the environment sounds and play it later, then record it again and play, back and forth.

but when it runs for couple of minutes,  it just crash and leave useless information,
what should I do with the crash log?  why does it caused a sigsegv instead of throw an exception?

```
 I/DEBUG   (  345): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Build fingerprint: 'ONEPLUS/A0001/A0001:4.3/JLS36C/1390465867:user/release-keys'
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Revision: '0'
    I/DEBUG   (  345): pid: 7884, tid: 7908, name: Binder_1  >>> /system/bin/mediaserver <<<
    I/DEBUG   (  345): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 00000060
    W/NativeCrashListener(  776): Couldn't find ProcessRecord for pid 7884
    D/NativeCrashListener(  776): Closing socket connection: FileDescriptor[272]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     r0 b2f8fd18  r1 00000000  r2 00000000  r3 00000003
    I/DEBUG   (  345): AM write failure (32 / Broken pipe)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     r4 b8787068  r5 00000001  r6 00000001  r7 00000002
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     r8 00001ecc  r9 b87276a0  sl 00000001  fp b86fb030
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     ip 00000002  sp b2f8fd18  lr b6e507c1  pc b6ee9ffc  cpsr 60000030
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d0  7473696765726e75  d1  7463656666457265
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d2  6f6e6b6e75202928  d3  6365666665206e77
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d4  34d34c2ebaaaa69a  d5  9a69a6175d75d555
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d6  5556db0baebaeaaa  d7  3f8000000000ac44
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d8  0000000000000000  d9  0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d10 0000000000000000  d11 0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d12 0000000000000000  d13 0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d14 0000000000000000  d15 0000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d16 6565636f7270202c  d17 206f7420676e6964
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d18 006900640065006d  d19 00410049002e0061
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d20 006f006900640075  d21 006e0069006c0046
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d22 0043007200650067  d23 006e00650069006c
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d24 3f9a4b4a85f3b526  d25 bf9a4b4aa02da45b
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d26 bc2803e87e9cca12  d27 4000000000000000
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d28 4001f53d66985c96  d29 3fcadbcacffa4b75
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     d30 3ff0000000000000  d31 3f69490d4c016d23
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     scr 20000010
    I/DEBUG   (  345): 
    I/DEBUG   (  345): backtrace:
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #00  pc 00048ffc  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so (android::AudioFlinger::EffectModule::setEnabled_l(bool)+123)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #01  pc 00049055  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so (android::AudioFlinger::EffectModule::setEnabled(bool)+24)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #02  pc 00049091  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so (android::AudioFlinger::EffectHandle::disable()+44)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #03  pc 000655c3  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::BnEffect::onTransact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+66)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #04  pc 000181b1  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::BBinder::transact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+60)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #05  pc 0001bbfd  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::executeCommand(int)+508)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #06  pc 0001c00b  /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+182)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #07  pc 0001fe05  /system/lib/libbinder.so
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #08  pc 00011a8d  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #09  pc 00011581  /system/lib/libutils.so
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #10  pc 0000cba0  /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #11  pc 0000cd1c  /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+208)
    I/DEBUG   (  345): 
    I/DEBUG   (  345): stack:
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fcd8  b327d0a0  /system/lib/hw/audio_policy.msm8974.so
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fcdc  0000000e  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fce0  0000000e  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fce4  0000000e  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fce8  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fcec  b874d028  [heap]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fcf0  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fcf4  b6e508c7  /system/lib/libutils.so (android::RefBase::weakref_type::attemptIncStrong(void const*)+150)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fcf8  b2f8fd18  [stack:7908]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fcfc  b8787080  [heap]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd00  00000001  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd04  b6eda57f  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so (android::wp<android::AudioFlinger::EffectChain>::promote() const+22)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd08  00000003  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd0c  b8787068  [heap]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd10  df0027ad  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd14  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #00  b2f8fd18  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd1c  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd20  b2f8fd34  [stack:7908]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd24  b8787068  [heap]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd28  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd2c  b6eea059  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so (android::AudioFlinger::EffectModule::setEnabled(bool)+28)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #01  b2f8fd30  b8787068  [heap]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd34  b8787074  [heap]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd38  b8785ed8  [heap]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd3c  b2f8fdd4  [stack:7908]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd40  00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd44  b6eea095  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so (android::AudioFlinger::EffectHandle::disable()+48)
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     #02  b2f8fd48  b8785ed8  [heap]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd4c  b6eea065  /system/lib/libaudioflinger.so (android::AudioFlinger::EffectHandle::disable())
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd50  b8785ed8  [heap]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd54  b2f8fdd4  [stack:7908]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd58  b2f8fe04  [stack:7908]
    I/DEBUG   (  345):          b2f8fd5c  b6de85c5  /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::BnEffect::onTransact(unsigned int, android::Parcel const&, android::Parcel*, unsigned int)+68)
    I/DEBUG   (  345): 
    I/DEBUG   (  345): memory near r0:
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     b2f8fcf8 b2f8fd18 b8787080 00000001 b6eda57f  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     b2f8fd08 00000003 b8787068 df0027ad 00000000  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     b2f8fd18 00000000 00000000 b2f8fd34 b8787068  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     b2f8fd28 00000000 b6eea059 b8787068 b8787074  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     b2f8fd38 b8785ed8 b2f8fdd4 00000000 b6eea095  
    I/DEBUG   (  345):     b2f8fd48 b8785ed8 b6eea065 b8785ed8 b2f8fdd4  

    I/DEBUG   (  345): 
    I/DEBUG   (  345): 
    I/DEBUG   (  345): -------- Memory information
    I/DEBUG   (  345): MemTotal:        2887628 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): MemFree:           92892 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Buffers:           48232 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Cached:          1071536 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): SwapCached:            0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Active:          1641524 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Inactive:         546400 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Active(anon):    1068956 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Inactive(anon):     5308 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Active(file):     572568 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Inactive(file):   541092 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Unevictable:         824 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Mlocked:               0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): HighTotal:       2185216 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): HighFree:           2932 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): LowTotal:         702412 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): LowFree:           89960 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): SwapTotal:             0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): SwapFre
    I/DEBUG   (  345): e:              0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Dirty:                44 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Writeback:             0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): AnonPages:       1068964 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Mapped:           215104 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Shmem:              5376 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Slab:              62000 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): SReclaimable:      25476 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): SUnreclaim:        36524 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): KernelStack:       12824 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): PageTables:        23780 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Bounce:                0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): WritebackTmp:          0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): CommitLimit:     1443812 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Committed_AS:   20408040 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): VmallocTotal:     122880 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): VmallocUsed:       25948 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): VmallocChunk: 
    I/DEBUG   (  345):      62900 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): 
    I/DEBUG   (  345): 
    I/DEBUG   (  345): 
    I/DEBUG   (  345): -------- Memory information
    I/DEBUG   (  345): MemTotal:        2887628 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): MemFree:           96988 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Buffers:           48232 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Cached:          1071784 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): SwapCached:            0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Active:          1637008 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Inactive:         546568 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Active(anon):    1064440 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Inactive(anon):     5308 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Active(file):     572568 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Inactive(file):   541260 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Unevictable:         824 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Mlocked:               0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): HighTotal:       2185216 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): HighFree:           3184 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): LowTotal:         702412 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): LowFree:           93804 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): SwapTotal:             0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): SwapFre
    I/DEBUG   (  345): e:              0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Dirty:               440 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Writeback:             0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): AnonPages:       1064368 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Mapped:           215104 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Shmem:              5376 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Slab:              62000 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): SReclaimable:      25476 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): SUnreclaim:        36524 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): KernelStack:       12824 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): PageTables:        23780 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): NFS_Unstable:          0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Bounce:                0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): WritebackTmp:          0 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): CommitLimit:     1443812 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): Committed_AS:   20403436 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): VmallocTotal:     122880 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): VmallocUsed:       25948 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): VmallocChunk: 
    I/DEBUG   (  345):      62900 kB
    I/DEBUG   (  345): 
    W/AudioSystem(  776): AudioFlinger server died!
    V/MaxxAudioService( 5028): setErrorCallback error=  100
    W/System.err( 7962): java.lang.IllegalStateException
    W/System.err( 7962):    at android.media.MediaPlayer._stop(Native Method)
    W/AudioSystem( 5028): AudioFlinger server died!
    I/ServiceManager(  333): service 'listen.service' died
    I/ServiceManager(  333): service 'media.audio_flinger' died
    I/ServiceManager(  333): service 'media.player' died
    I/ServiceManager(  333): service 'media.camera' died
    I/ServiceManager(  333): service 'media.audio_policy' died
    W/AudioSystem( 7962): AudioFlinger server died!
    W/IMediaDeathNotifier( 7962): media server died
    W/AudioSystem( 7962): AudioPolicyService server died!
    W/AudioSystem(  776): AudioPolicyService server died!
    W/System.err( 7962):    at android.media.MediaPlayer.stop(MediaPlayer.java:1064)
    W/System.err( 7962):    at com.kongdao.avatar.app.sound.SoundController.stopPlay(SoundController.java:210)
    E/IAudioFlinger( 7962): createEffect error: Unknown error 2147483646
    E/AudioEffect( 7962): set(): AudioFlinger could not create effect, status: -2147483646
    E/visualizers-JNI( 7962): Visualizer initCheck failed -1
    E/Visualizer-JAVA( 7962): Error code -1 when initializing Visualizer.
    W/System.err( 7962):    at com.kongdao.avatar.app.sound.SoundController.play(SoundController.java:180)
    W/System.err( 7962):    at com.kongdao.avatar.app.sound.SoundController$3.onLoadComp(SoundController.java:122)
    W/System.err( 7962):    at com.kongdao.avatar.app.sound.SoundTouchThread.run(SoundTouchThread.java:128)
    W/System.err( 7962): java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot initialize Visualizer engine, error: -1
    W/System.err( 7962):    at android.media.audiofx.Visualizer.<init>(Visualizer.java:199)
    W/System.err( 7962):    at com.kongdao.avatar.app.sound.AudioCapture.<init>(AudioCapture.java:63)
    W/System.err( 7962):    at com.kongdao.avatar.app.animation.AnimationTask.getData(AnimationTask.java:371)
    W/AudioEffect( 5028): IEffect died
    W/IMediaDeathNotifier( 5041): media server died
    E/MediaPlayer( 5041): error (100, 0)
    W/System.err( 7962):    at com.kongdao.avatar.app.animation.AnimationTask.doSpeakAnim(AnimationTask.java:313)
    E/MediaPlayer( 5041): error (100, 0)
    W/CameraBase( 5225): Camera service died!
    D/PowerManagerService(  776): updateWakeLockSummaryLocked: mWakefulness=Awake, mWakeLockSummary=0x23
    D/PowerManagerService(  776): updateScreenStateLocked: mDisplayReady=true, newScreenState=2, mWakefulness=1, mWakeLockSummary=0x23, mUserActivitySummary=0x1, mBootCompleted=true
    W/System.err( 7962):    at com.kongdao.avatar.app.animation.AnimationTask.run(AnimationTask.java:233)
    W/System.err( 7962):    at java.util.Timer$TimerImpl.run(Timer.java:284)
    E/AudioCapture( 7962): captureData() :  com.kongdao.avatar.app.sound.AudioCapture@4327bb40 error: -1
    D/spl     ( 7962):    SPEAK 0
    I/ServiceManager( 7962): Waiting for service media.audio_flinger...
```

also there's another crash log generated by online test platform:

```
#108-0118:07:17.273I/DEBUG(5002):pid:4244,tid:4252,name:Compiler>>>com.avatar.app<<<
#208-0118:07:17.273I/DEBUG(5002):signal11(SIGSEGV),code1(SEGV_MAPERR),faultaddrfff50004
#308-0118:07:17.293D/AudioMTKStreamInManager(161):CopyBufferToClient,mMaxProcessTime=5297154
#408-0118:07:17.293D/AudioMTKStreamInManager(161):AudioMTkRecordThreadreadperiodtime=5425692
#508-0118:07:17.367V/ActivityManager(654):getTasks:max=1,flags=0,receiver=null
#608-0118:07:17.368V/ActivityManager(654):com.avatar.app/.OriginActivity:task=TaskRecord{434b4ea0#236Acom.avatar.appU0}
#708-0118:07:17.368V/ActivityManager(654):com.avatar.app/.MainActivity:task=TaskRecord{434b4ea0#236Acom.avatar.appU0}
#808-0118:07:17.368V/ActivityManager(654):Wehavependingthumbnails:null
#908-0118:07:17.385I/DEBUG(5002):r0ffd7ffder1ffd7ffd8r2fff50000r3fff50000
#1008-0118:07:17.385I/DEBUG(5002):r47abe4358r5000007d8r6ffd7f800r700000005
#1108-0118:07:17.385I/DEBUG(5002):r800000005r900000090sl00000000fp73d211e4
#1208-0118:07:17.385I/DEBUG(5002):ip40188c14sp72e7ba10lr40133fd4pc40134270cpsra0000010
#1308-0118:07:17.386I/DEBUG(5002):
#1408-0118:07:17.386I/DEBUG(5002):backtrace:
#1508-0118:07:17.386I/DEBUG(5002):#00pc00016270/system/lib/libc.so(dlmalloc+1252)
#1608-0118:07:17.386I/DEBUG(5002):#01pc0001b3b4/system/lib/libc.so(dlcalloc+44)
#1708-0118:07:17.386I/DEBUG(5002):#02pc0000cf54/system/lib/libc.so(calloc+16)
#1808-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):#03pc0008034d/system/lib/libdvm.so(dvmBasicBlockOptimization(CompilationUnit*)+108)
#1908-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):#04pc0007dafb/system/lib/libdvm.so(dvmCompileTrace(JitTraceDescription*,int,JitTranslationInfo*,long(*)[64],int)+2438)
#2008-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):#05pc00089d9f/system/lib/libdvm.so(dvmCompilerDoWork(CompilerWorkOrder*)+46)
#2108-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):#06pc0007be2f/system/lib/libdvm.so
#2208-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):#07pc00055b43/system/lib/libdvm.so
#2308-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):#08pc0000e4a4/system/lib/libc.so(__thread_entry+72)
#2408-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):
#2508-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):stack:
#2608-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9d000000000
#2708-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9d473d21ce8
#2808-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9d873d224d0
#2908-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9dc73d224d0
#3008-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9e040a77810
#3108-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9e400000008
#3208-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9e873d22518
#3308-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9ec73d22518
#3408-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9f040a77810
#3508-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9f400000040
#3608-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9f8068fa738
#3708-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9fc00054e60
#3808-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba00000007d0
#3908-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba040000001c
#4008-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba08df0027ad
#4108-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba0c00000000
#4208-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):#0072e7ba1073d22450
#4308-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba1400000007
#4408-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba1873d22478
#4508-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba1c40a48557/system/lib/libdvm.so(dvmCompilerApplyInstructionScheduling(CompilationUnit*)+1206)
#4608-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba2000000000
#4708-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba2400000000
#4808-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba2800000004
#4908-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba2c73d22464
#5008-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba3000000001
#5108-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba3473d22428
#5208-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba3873d22328
#5308-0118:07:17.387I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba3c40a70c70/system/lib/libdvm.so
#5408-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba4073d22478
#5508-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba4472e7bbbc[stack:4252]
#5608-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba48000007d0
#5708-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba4c00000000
#5808-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):................
#5908-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):#0172e7bab800000006
#6008-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7babc00000006
#6108-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7bac072e7bd1c[stack:4252]
#6208-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7bac472e7bbbc[stack:4252]
#6308-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7bac872e7bbbc[stack:4252]
#6408-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7bacc40a77814
#6508-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7bad00000001c
#6608-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7bad400000006
#6708-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7bad800000004
#6808-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7badc4012af58/system/lib/libc.so(calloc+20)
#6908-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):#0272e7bae00000000a
#7008-0118:07:17.388I/DEBUG(5002):72e7bae440a38351/system/lib/libdvm.so(dvmBasicBlockOptimization(CompilationUnit*)+112)
#7108-0118:07:17.390I/DEBUG(5002):
#7208-0118:07:17.390I/DEBUG(5002):memorynearr4:
#7308-0118:07:17.390I/DEBUG(5002):7abe43380018001a000700140011000800010008................
#7408-0118:07:17.390I/DEBUG(5002):7abe4348000b00070000000500040002ffe2fff7................
#7508-0118:07:17.390I/DEBUG(5002):7abe435800002018ffd7ffdefff3ffe000090003...............
#7608-0118:07:17.390I/DEBUG(5002):7abe4368fff50000fff7fff8ffe5ffedffefffe9................
#7708-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):7abe4378fff4fff3ffeafff0ffd8ffe2ffe8ffda................
#7808-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):
#7908-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):memorynearfp:
#8008-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):73d211c473d211340000000073d21728000000004..s....(..s....
#8108-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):73d211d400000000000000000000000000000000................
#8208-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):73d211e400000002000000000000009200000000................
#8308-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):73d211f400000000000000000000000000000000................
#8408-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):73d2120400000000000000000000000000000000................
#8508-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):
#8608-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):memorynearip:
#8708-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):40188bf400000000000000000000000000000000................
#8808-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):40188c0400000000000000000000000000000000................
#8908-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):40188c14740676cc0000063f0000001000001fb8.v.t?...........
#9008-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):40188c2440f200007a85c8087ade102000200000...@...z..z...
#9108-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):40188c3400000b62068fa7380000000000000000b...8...........
#9208-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):
#9308-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):memorynearsp:
#9408-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):72e7b9f040a7781000000040068fa73800054e60.x.@@...8...`N..
#9508-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba00000007d00000001cdf0027ad00000000.........'......
#9608-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba1073d224500000000773d2247840a48557P$.s....x$.sW..@
#9708-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba2000000000000000000000000473d22464............d$.s
#9808-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):72e7ba300000000173d2242873d2232840a70c70....($.s(#.sp..@
#9908-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):
#10008-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):codearoundpc:
#10108-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):4013425011a02001e35300001affffece3540000.....S.......T.
#10208-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):40134260035200000a000124e35200000a00000d..R.$.....R.....
#10308-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):40134270e5920004e3c01007e0653001e1530006.........0e...S.
#10408-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):4013428031a06003e592301031a04002e3530000.`.1.0...@.1..S.
#10508-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):401342900a000001e1a02003eafffff4e5923014............0..
#10608-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):
#10708-0118:07:17.391I/DEBUG(5002):codearoundlr:
#10808-0118:07:17.392I/DEBUG(5002):40133fb4e5821008e58c3004e78c1001e5845004.....0.......P..
#10908-0118:07:17.392I/DEBUG(5002):40133fc4e2844008eaffffe0e2800d07ebffde07.@..............
#11008-0118:07:17.392I/DEBUG(5002):40133fd4e35000000affff77e3a04000eaffffe1..P.w....@......
#11108-0118:07:17.392I/DEBUG(5002):40133fe4ebfff13feaffff6ee59f2d38e285500b?...n...8-...P..
#11208-0118:07:17.392I/DEBUG(5002):40133ff4e3c55007e08f3002e593c004e35c0000.P...0........\.
#11308-0118:07:17.392I/DEBUG(5002):
#11408-0118:07:17.392I/DEBUG(5002):memorymaparoundfaultaddrfff50004:
#11508-0118:07:17.392I/DEBUG(5002):bec36000-bec57000[stack]
#11608-0118:07:17.392I/DEBUG(5002):(nomapforaddress)
#11708-0118:07:17.392I/DEBUG(5002):ffff0000-ffff1000[vectors]
#11808-0118:07:17.468V/ActivityManager(654):getTasks:max=1,flags=0,receiver=null
#11908-0118:07:17.468V/ActivityManager(654):com.avatar.app/.OriginActivity:task=TaskRecord{434b4ea0#236Acom.avatar.appU0}
#12008-0118:07:17.469V/ActivityManager(654):com.avatar.app/.MainActivity:task=TaskRecord{434b4ea0#236Acom.avatar.appU0}
#12108-0118:07:17.469V/ActivityManager(654):Wehavependingthumbnails:null
#12208-0118:07:17.529V/ViewRootImpl(823):scheduleConsumeBatchedInput:mConsumeBatchedInputScheduled=false,mFirstPendingInputEvent=null,this=ViewRoot{425d3c68,ident=47}
#12308-0118:07:17.530V/ActivityManager(654):getTasks:max=1,flags=0,receiver=null
#12408-0118:07:17.530V/ActivityManager(654):com.avatar.app/.OriginActivity:task=TaskRecord{434b4ea0#236Acom.avatar.appU0}
#12508-0118:07:17.530V/ActivityManager(654):com.avatar.app/.MainActivity:task=TaskRecord{434b4ea0#236Acom.avatar.appU0}
#12608-0118:07:17.530V/ActivityManager(654):Wehavependingthumbnails:null
#12708-0118:07:17.538V/ViewRootImpl(823):doConsumeBatchedInput:frameTimeNanos=29815329963933,this=ViewRoot{425d3c68,ident=47}
#12808-0118:07:17.539I/BufferQueue(157):[](this:0x4289d790,api:2)newGraphicBufferneeded
#12908-0118:07:17.539D/BufferQueue(157):[OLD]gb:NULL
#13008-0118:07:17.539I/GraphicBuffer(157):allocatebuffer(w:688h:505f:1)handle(0x4289eb08)err(0)
#13108-0118:07:17.539I/BufferQueue(157):[NEW]gb=0x441ff198,handle=0x4289eb08,w=684,h=505,s=688,fmt=1
#13208-0118:07:17.539D/GraphicBuffer(823):createhandle(0x74df3110)(w:688,h:505,f:1)
#13308-0118:07:17.555I/SurfaceTextureClient(157):[](this:0x43c77870,api:2)[void*android::SurfaceTexture::createImage(EGLDisplay,constandroid::sp&)]
#13408-0118:07:17.555D/SurfaceTextureClient(157):GraphicBuffer:gb=0x441ff198handle=0x4289eb08
#13508-0118:07:17.555D/SurfaceTextureClient(157):EGLImage:dpy=0x1,img=0x10000013
#13608-0118:07:17.556I/SurfaceTextureClient(157):[STC::queueBuffer](this:0x4074f008)fps:33.85,dur:1122.70,max:380.22,min:15.90
#13708-0118:07:17.556I/BufferQueue(157):[FramebufferSurface](this:0x4074c3b0,api:1)[release]fps:33.85,dur:1122.65,max:380.26,min:15.90
#13808-0118:07:17.556I/BufferQueue(157):[FramebufferSurface](this:0x4074c3b0,api:1)[queue]fps:33.85,dur:1122.65,max:380.31,min:15.90
#13908-0118:07:17.569V/ActivityManager(654):getTasks:max=1,flags=0,receiver=null
#14008-0118:07:17.569V/ActivityManager(654):com.avatar.app/.OriginActivity:task=TaskRecord{434b4ea0#236Acom.avatar.appU0}
#14108-0118:07:17.569V/ActivityManager(654):com.avatar.app/.MainActivity:task=TaskRecord{434b4ea0#236Acom.avatar.appU0}
#14208-0118:07:17.569V/ActivityManager(654):Wehavependingthumbnails:null
#14308-0118:07:17.670V/ActivityManager(654):getTasks:max=1,flags=0,receiver=null
#14408-0118:07:17.670V/ActivityManager(654):com.avatar.app/.OriginActivity:task=TaskRecord{434b4ea0#236Acom.avatar.appU0}
#14508-0118:07:17.670V/ActivityManager(654):com.avatar.app/.MainActivity:task=TaskRecord{434b4ea0#236Acom.avatar.appU0}
```

Comment: Difficult to tell without the code...
Why you use MediaPlayer instead of AudioTracker? 

The point is that MediaPlayer only recognises specific format, like MP3 or OGG, 
while AudioTracker is the correct way to play raw sound data.

Comment: I could post the code snippet, but there were too many, not sure which part is necessary...